'Error fetching data: TypeError: setApodData is not a function at fetchData' New react dev
im in need of some react help. I currently work as a backend developer but ive recently been trying to get into some front end work. So im just try to build a small project using some NASA Api's with a Spring boot backend and react frontend. My backend is working find. but being realitivly new to frontend im having some troubles. When i start up my server i get the proper backend response but i get an error from my front end telling me that 'setApodData' is not a function and theres just a blank white page. ive added logs to see where it breaks and I can see the data is being logged but not being passed to the setApodData, it seems after the 'console.log("after await");' log it stops and throws the setApodData is not a function error ive been searching and using all the AI's to try to find a soultion and everywhere i look it tells me that my code looks correct. the code i attached below is using react with the materialUI library. I will also attach the console logs and network logs. I have attached code and screenshots below. The backend is being called fine. Im really scratching my head. if you need any additional info let me know. Thanks!
import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react";
import { Card, CardContent,CardMedia, Typography } from "@mui/material";


const ApodCard = () =>{
    const  {apodData, setApodData} = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try{
                console.log("before response");
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/get-apod');
                console.log("after response");
                if(!response.ok){
                    throw new Error('HTTP error!, Status: ${response.status}');
                }
                console.log("before await");
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log("Fetched data:", data);
                console.log("after await");
                setApodData(data);
                console.log("after setApodData");
                console.log("Fetched data:", data);
            }catch(error){
                console.error('Error fetching data: ', error);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    },
   [] );

   return(
    apodData && (
        <Card>
        {apodData.media_type === 'image' ? (
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            image={apodData.hdurl}
            alt={apodData.title}
          />
        ):(<CardContent></CardContent>)}


        </Card>
    )
   )
};
export default ApodCard;

Console
Network tab
ive added logs to see where it breaks and it seems after the 'console.log("after await");' log it stops and throws the setApodData is not a function error ive been searching and using all the AI's to try to find a soultion and everywhere i look it tells me that my code looks correct.

{ apodData, setApodData } = useState(null); replace this with
const [apodData, setApodData] = useState(null);

useState returns an array with two elements: the current state value and a function to update that state. Use array destructuring to assign these values to apodData and setApodData.
So the corrected version would be,
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Card, CardContent, CardMedia, Typography } from "@mui/material";

const ApodCard = () => {
    const [apodData, setApodData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            console.log("before response");
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/get-apod');
            console.log("after response");
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
            }
            console.log("before await");
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log("Fetched data:", data);
            console.log("after await");
            setApodData(data);
            console.log("after setApodData");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);

return (
    apodData && (
        <Card>
            {apodData.media_type === 'image' ? (
                <CardMedia
                    component="img"
                    image={apodData.hdurl}
                    alt={apodData.title}
                />
            ) : (
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                        {apodData.explanation}
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
            )}
        </Card>
    )
);
};

    export default ApodCard;

I added Typography component to render text if the media isnt always an image.

You should be setting state like this
const [apodData, setApodData] = useState(null);

The destructed variables should be in an array []
